# asPercent with two datasets

Tags: graphite

imagine I have this two datasets in Graphite:

```
My.Host.DataTable.*_CurrentConnections
My.Host.DataTable.*_MaxPermittedConnections
```

I need to plot 1 line for each of the data points (both have the same size) representing the usage percentage for each point.

I was trying to do this: `asPercent(My.Host.DataTable.*_CurrentConnections, My.Host.DataTable.*_MaxPermittedConnections)`, but it looks like it only works when the second value is static.

Any ideas?